# Error setting up new project with angular/cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I am new to npm and Angular 2, I am trying to setup a new Angular 2 project using angular/cli.

I am currently running:

Node v8.9.3
npm v5.6.0
Windows 10

First, I ran `npm install -g @angular/cli` which seemed to install just fine. Then I went to the folder where I wanted to start my project, ran `ng new my-app` but kept getting this error.

> npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.22-1: angular-cli has been
>   renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
>
> npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing
>   Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
>
> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
>
> npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs
>   4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
>
> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2
>   or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2
>   or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4
>   for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
>
> npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1
>   || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 ||
>
> > =4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.9.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 ||
>   ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself.
>
> npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.2 requires a peer of
>   webpack@^2.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN string-replace-loader@1.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2
>   || 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself.
>
> npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none
>   is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of
>   webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must
>   install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3
>   (node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Web Development\Projects\angular 2
>   practice\my-app\node_modules\@angular-cli\ast-tools\node_modules\mkdirp\bin\cmd.js
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -4058
>
> npm ERR! syscall chmod
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Web
>   Development\Projects\angular 2
>   practice\my-app\node_modules\@angular-cli\ast-tools\node_modules\mkdirp\bin\cmd.js'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jason
>   Kervin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-12T00_57_54_496Z-debug.log
>
> Package install failed, see above.

Answer (score 3):

Try these steps:

1. npm cache clean --force
2. Open cmd and go to your current user  cd C:\Users{your user name
   here}
3. npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
4. npm install -g npm@latest
5. npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 1):

From the command line run

```
ng -v
```

This should output 1.6.0. If it doesn't you have an older version of the CLI installed.

Run:

```
npm cache --force clean
```

And then:

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

If that doesnt work remove the folders in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: Hmm, I tried to uninstall but now I am getting an error trying npm install @angular/cli -g

Comment: npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha512-dIDiZTu1NhG2Yq3KNa5vYMKSAOnjYjkOgQEWKmhOqWvrZ/sPVmP3xx9O2Z61traxDhTjNQQgMUAgDRDEYsmhWg== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-dIDiZTu1NhG2Yq3KNa5vYMKSAOnjYjkOgQEWKmhOqWvrZ/sPVmP3xx9O2Z61traxDhTjNQQgMUAgDRDEYsmhWg== but got sha512-h4GvUIQppEvv0Y34DgtqHFVq8uLRVL5X6XhmWS0tMi2/uMVIA3HMgMvyJUqL5jq9mMl0Xjr13JR2pMJb7i5aEA==. (3366 bytes)

Comment: npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/original: Integrity verification failed for sha512-dIDiZTu1NhG2Yq3KNa5vYMKSAOnjYjkOgQEWKmhOqWvrZ/sPVmP3xx9O2Z61traxDhTjNQQgMUAgDRDEYsmhWg== (C:\Users\Jason Kervin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\74\80\e2653bb53611b662adca35ae6f60c29200e9e362390e8101162a684ea96beb67fb0f5663f7c71f4ed99eb5b6b6b10e14e33504203140200d10c462c9a15a

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: That worked! I was able to reinstall successfully, one last question. When I use `ng new my-app` should I be in the directory for my app?

Comment: Great, Thanks for all the help!

Comment: maybe add `npm uninstall angular-cli` since he clearly has an outdated version with a different name

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines:

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research on this I came to a final solution,
I tried lots of solutions but not worked for me.
Try this it works for me,
I'm using Ubuntu.

Uninstall angular cli.

Hit following command,

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

check version if version still present, check path

```
which ng
```

It will give following output

```
/usr/bin/ng
```

Now delete this by using

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ng
```

then remove angular package

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular
```

Now your angular cli is completely removed from your machine.

Now check angulars latest stable version and install it.

if problem is still present than uninstall node and delete global node_modules folder.

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules
```

And install node and angular again.

And try to create new project.
Hope it will work for you.
Thank You!